# Using SQLite Data for creating chart

Tags: android, sqlite, file, charts

I have the following question: I should create a chart in app activity. The first axis of this chart is temperature and the second is date when such temperature was. I am thinking of using SQLite for keeping this data, because I think that this data is easier to process. Or there is no need in it and it's better to use usual file. But how can I process the date if it keeps in format dd.mm.yyyy in such case?

Comment: Vital reading for using date and time values in sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype (and the rest of that page) and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Sqlite is fine. 
Then use epoch for date/time. I.e seconds or mSec since 1.1.1970.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart that may help you in your app.

Sqlite would be a good to store all your data.